# os Path "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I'm trying to open files from this path `C:\Users\Usuario\Llamas\llamas-python\face` but I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

```
  im1 = Image.open(f' ./llamas-python/face/{face_files[item["Face"]]}.png').convert('RGBA')
```

Any help¡?

Comment: The path to the image is relative since it starts with a dot. It could work if you run the script from `C:\Users\Usuario\Llamas`. To work running the script from other directory you should pass an absolute path to the image.

Comment: Yeah i runneing it from this path `C:\Users\Usuario\Llamas` but i'm getting the same error

Comment: ` ./llamas-python/face/` has a space in starting. Also, `/` is linux style, for windows you have to use `\\` or raw `r` strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
im1 = Image.open(f'.\\llamas-python\\face\\{face_files[item["Face"]]}.png').convert('RGBA')
```